# Can I watch the WWDC from the beginning when the event has not finished?

Tags: streaming

I want to watch the WWDC tomorrow however I will traveling home from college. This means that I will miss some of it and do not want to start watching it half way through. Is there a way how I can start watching the WWDC at the beginning when I start watching it tomorrow?

Comment: Just in case you don't get an answer, I can tell you that under the circumstances, live blogs can be a tolerable substitute for watching the stream. (Source: Experience when Apple events happened during school hours.) I recommend the one at [Macworld](http://www.macworld.com/article/2926563/live-blog-apples-wwdc-2015-keynote-starts-10am-june-8.html), but I'm sure there are countless others if you want to look for them yourself.

Comment: @user24601 Thanks for that. Think I remembered that Mac Rumors also do that. If I cannot find a way how to play from the beginning reading the post will be a great way to catch up with the program so I don't miss much info. Thanks. Still looking for a streaming way though. :) . This is the issues with time zones. That is 5PM my time

Comment: If you don't mind waiting till the keynote has finished Apple posts the whole thing almost right away...

Comment: I know. The only issue is that leaves me very little time for the rest of the evening. That is why I want to play it from the beginning while it is still streaming. Thanks for that information anyway.

Comment: This would be a huge feature for many people. I go thru this every year because of my work schedule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE: The stream is officially posted in a replayable state, just like any other online video, located [here](http://www.apple.com/live/2015-june-event/). It's also the latest entry in Apple's "Apple Keynotes" podcast, available for download on iTunes and iDevices [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/apple-keynotes/id275834665?mt=2).

Since no one seems to have given the answer iProgram was hoping for, I might as well make this a proper answer in case other people have the same question.

Under the circumstances, live blogs can be a tolerable substitute for watching the stream. (Source: Experience when Apple events happened during school hours.) I personally recommend the ones at [Macworld](http://www.macworld.com/article/2926563/live-blog-apples-wwdc-2015-keynote-starts-10am-june-8.html) and [iMore](http://www.imore.com/wwdc-2015-liveblog), but there are countless others that you can find online if you search for them.

Good luck, and enjoy the keynote, however you end up experiencing it!

Comment: I may do that for now. Would you also recommend Mac Rumours as well?

Comment: I know MacRumors is a decent news site, but I can't speak from experience about their live blogs. You're welcome to try it!

Comment: Also, I think I'll come back here in a few hours with an actual answer to your question. If there's a boring part of the keynote that I don't mind missing a few seconds of, I'll open a new tab and see if rewinding is possible. Check and see if I've updated this answer when you get home and are ready to start watching.

Comment: Just realised. It is at 6PM. I thought it was at 5PM. Im there on time! I am still open for answers for myself and other peoples future reference.

Comment: I just updated with an official answer.

Comment: Thanks for that. Good job I was here for all of it! :) Blogs/posts for it are always good too since you can catch up quickly.